# How do you sort a multidimensional list by absolute value in python

Tags: python, list, sorting, absolute

I've got a 3 dimensional list, two of the columns include strings, and one an int. How do I sort the second column by absolute value? I've tried:

```
sorted(yestForSort,key=lambda l:l[1], reverse=True)
```

but this doesn't give me absolute value. I've tried:

```
def sorting(numbers_array):
    return sorted(numbers_array, key = abs(numbers_array))
```

but this doesn't work on 2 dimensions.

Comment: Can you post a sample?

Comment: Is it three dimensional or a list of length-3 lists?

Comment: Your first snippet is almost correct - the `key` param should be `lambda l: abs(l[1])`. Keep in mind that reverse=True will sort the list in reverse order

Comment: Just to be clear, is the goal to sort by absolute value or to treat the integers as unsigned values? If the goal is to treat the integers as unsigned values, one way to do this for two's complement numbers is to complement the sign bit before doing a compare.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way:

```
>>> l = [['a', 10, 'b'], ['c', -2, 'd'], ['e', 5, 'f']]
>>> sorted(l, key=lambda sublist: abs(sublist[1]))
[['c', -2, 'd'], ['e', 5, 'f'], ['a', 10, 'b']]
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked as desired. I'm not sure how you came up with 'sublist' though.